# jpgraph graph labels not fully displayed

Tags: php, jpgraph

I am using the jpgraph library to make data graphs in php. Making the graph goes problemless, but the **axis labels are not fully shown**. 
Changing font to a smaller font and size does not make a difference and when trying to find anything in the documentation I found no solution. Graph is constructed like the basic examples which are shown fine.

[image]

Any idea's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to change the margins?

```
$graph->SetMargin(w, x, y, z);
```